# Find the function $f(k)$, $k > 1$ that is the largest integer and is a divisor of $n^k - n$ for all integers $n$.

Tags: number-theory

For example,$ f (2) = 2$, and $f(3) = 6$.

I don't know what kind of technique I should use.

By putting $n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$ it's even hard to know if $f(2) = 2$ for ALL integer $n$.

Comment: Hint: $f(k)$ equals the product of all prime natural numbers $p$ such that $p-1$ divide $k-1$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A027760

Comment: Thank you. I've been taking a look at it.

Comment: Hi, WE Tutorial School. That f(k) works. I plug k = 2, 3, 4,.. and I get the correct sequence. But can you elaborate a little more on that idea? It's hard to see how (p-1) and (k-1) come up. I reviewed the Fermat's Little Theorem, but it only states that n^k - n is divisible by k when k is prime, but it's hard to deduce anything from it to your statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1387249/72152?