# Prove: $2730|(n^{13}-n),n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: divisibility

$2730=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13$

$n^{13}-n=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)(n^8+n^4+1)$

Divisibility by $2$ and $3$ follows from the product of two and three successive terms.

Divisibility by $5$ follows from Fermat's little theorem:
$$n^{5-1}\equiv1(\mod 5)\Rightarrow 5|(n^{13}-n)=(n^4-1)(n^8+n^4+1)$$

How to prove divisibility by $7$ and $13$?

Comment: This question is asked see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596074/how-to-show-that-2730-mid-n13-n-forall-n-in-mathbbn?rq=1

Comment: You know Fermat's little theorem but don't apply it to $13$ and $7$? Why?

Answer (score 1):

- You have also by Fermat's little theorem :

$$n^{13}\equiv n\pmod{13}$$

because $13$ is prime.

- Be careful, you have $n(n^4-1)(n^8+n^4+1)=n^{13}-n$, I think you made a typo.
- Dr Sonnhard Graubner treat the case $7$ perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

note that $$n \equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \mod 7$$ then $$n^{13}\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \mod 7$$