# $a^{33}\equiv a\pmod{4080}$ for all odd $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any odd integer $a$, show that $a^{33} \equiv a \pmod{4080}$.
I have attempted this problem in the following way:

Observe that $4080 = 2^4 \times 3 \times 5 \times 17 = 2 \times 15 \times 4 \times 2 \times 17$.\
$\bullet$ Since $a$ is odd, so $\gcd(a, 2\times 15) = 1$. Thus, $a^{\phi(30)} \equiv 1 \pmod{30}$ along with
$$\phi(30) = \phi(2 \times 3 \times 5) = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times (1 - \frac{1}{2})(1 - \frac{1}{3})
(1 - \frac{1}{5}) = 30(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{2}{3}) (\frac{4}{5}) = 8$$ yields $a^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{30}$ i.e. $a^{32} \equiv 1
\pmod{30}$.\
$\bullet$ Since $a$ is odd, so $\gcd(a, 2\times 17) = 1$. Thus, $a^{\phi(34)} \equiv 1 \pmod{34}$ along with
$$\phi(34) = \phi(2 \times 17) = 2 \times 17 \times (1 - \frac{1}{2})(1 - \frac{1}{17}) = 34(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{16}{17})
 = 16$$ yields $a^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{34}$ i.e. $a^{32} \equiv 1 \pmod{34}$.\
$\bullet$ Since $a$ is odd, so $\gcd(a, 16) = 1$. Thus, $a^{\phi(16)} \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$ along with
$$\phi(16) = \phi(2^4) = 2^4 - 2^3 = 8$$ yields $a^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$ i.e. $a^{32} \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$.\
Now, $\rm{lcm}(30, 34, 16) = 4080$, so from these congruences, we have
$$a^{32} \equiv 1 \pmod{\rm{lcm}(30, 34, 16)} \equiv 1 \pmod{4080}$$
and hence $a^{33} \equiv a \pmod{4080}$.
\end{enumerate}

The issue is that in "Since $a$ is odd, so $\gcd(a, 2\times 15) = 1$", if we choose $a = 3$, an odd integer, then $\gcd(a, 2\times 15) \neq 1$.

Comment: It is likely that techniques similar to those used in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/596074/11619) will help you.

Comment: Arithmetic error: 4080=(2^4)(17)(5)(3) not (2^3)((17)(5)(3). Also "since $a$ is odd so $\gcd (a,2\times 15)=1"$ is false. What if $a=5$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ 3\mid a \,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid a^{\large 33}\!-a.\,$ Ditto for $\,p=5,17.\,$ So we can reduce to the case that  $\,a\,$ is coprime to $2,3,5,17,\,$ i.e. $\,a\,$ is coprime to $4080,\,$ where we can combine the Euler results at each prime.

**Remark** $\ $ See also [Carmichael's Lambda function,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) a generalization of [Euler's phi function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: More generally see the special case when $m$ is squarefree $(e = 1)\,$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959386/242)