# Analogous results to Euler's theorem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Fermat's little theorem and its generalization, Euler's theorem holds for pair of relatively prime integers. Are there any analogous results for not relatively prime integers ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The following generalization of Euler-Fermat often proves handy.

**Theorem** $\  $ Suppose that $\ m\in \mathbb N\ $ has the prime factorization $\:m = p_1^{e_{\:1}}\cdots\:p_k^{e_k}\ $ and suppose that for all $\,i,\,$  $\ e_i\le e\ $ and $\ \phi(p_i^{e_{\:i}})\mid f.\ $ Then $\ m\mid a^e\,(a^f-1)\ $ for all $\: a\in \mathbb Z.$

**Proof** $\ $ Notice that if $\ p_i\mid a\ $ then $\:p_i^{e_{\:i}}\ |\ a^e\ $ by $\ e_i \le e.\: $ Else $\:a\:$ is coprime to $\: p_i\:$ so by Euler's phi theorem, $\!\bmod q = p_i^{e_{\:i}}\!:\, \ a^{\phi(q)}\equiv 1 \Rightarrow\ a^f\equiv 1\, $ by $\: \phi(q)\mid f.\ $  Since all $\ p_i^{e_{\:i}}\ |\  a^e\ (a^f - 1)\ $ so too does their lcm = product = $m$.

**Examples** $\ $ You can find many illuminating examples in prior questions, e.g. below

[$24\mid a^3(a^2-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408201/242)

[$40\mid a^3(a^4-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/637468/242)

[$88\mid a^5(a^{20}-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1316052/242)

[$6p\mid a\,b^p - b\,a^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003925/242)

Answer (score 0):

A small variant holds even without the coprime condition. It's true that
$$ a^p \equiv a \pmod p$$
even if $p \mid a$, for instance. Working a bit harder, you can show that
$$ a^{n - \varphi(n)} \equiv a^n \pmod n$$
as well, even if $\gcd(a,n) \neq 1$.

Comment: A special case of the result I mentioned.