# Find all positive integers $n$ satisfying the following congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have been asked to find $n$ satisfying

$n^{17} \equiv n\;\;$(mod $4080$)

I'm truly unsure how to even begin to attempt this. Is there a theorem or property of congruences that I should be identifying as useful for this problem?

Comment: Try the Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Isn't that used to solve systems of congruences, as opposed to single problems? How could it be applied here?

Comment: $4080=2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 17$. You can solve it modulo each of those prime power factors (keeping Fermat's little theorem and Euler's theorem in mind), and then combine the solutions with the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by saying solve it module each of those factors. Do you mean solving 4 separate instances of $n^{17} \equiv n\;$(mod $2^{4})$, $n^{17} \equiv n\;$(mod $3)$, and so on? How is this done using Fermat's little theorem? (Sorry but I'm not used to solving congruence problems involving n on both sides of the relation).

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. What does Fermat/Euler's theorem modulo 5 say? What does that tell you about $n^{17} \pmod{5}$? Which values for $n$ therefore satisfy $n^{17}\equiv n \pmod 5$ ?

Comment: See also [Carmichael's lambda function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), noting that $\lambda(4080)=16$.

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, for $p \nmid n$, $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ and so $n^{k(p-1)+1}\equiv n \pmod p$ holds for all $n$ (as it holds trivilally for multiples of $p$).

Note that $4080=2^4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot17$. By our initial observation, it follows that the congruence $n^{17}\equiv n$ holds modulo $p$ for $p=3,5 $ or $17$. Note that, modulo $16$, if $n$ is even the congruence holds iff $16|n$, and if not, then $n^8\equiv1\pmod {16}$ (By Fermat-Euler or just noticing that fourth powers of odd numbers are $1$ modulo $16$), whence $n^{17}\equiv n\pmod {16}$.

Finally, by chinese remainder theorem, it follows that $n^{17}\equiv n \pmod {16\cdot3\cdot5\cdot17}$ holds iff $n$ is odd or a multple of $16$.

Comment: **Counterexample** $\ 2^{17}\equiv 2\,$ fails $\!\bmod 16\,$ so also $\!\bmod 4080.\ $ The case $n$ odd is already done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2107571/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque, thanks. Corrected now.