# Find the biggest number $k$ such that $k| n^{55}-n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find the biggest integer number $k$ such that $k$ divides $n^{ 55 }-n$, where $n$ is any integer number.

This question was a challenge from my teacher, here's my attempt :

- because  $\left( n \right) \left( n-1 \right) \left( { n }^{ 53 }+{ n }^{ 52 }+{ n }^{ 51 }+...+n+1 \right) \equiv 0 \pmod k $, therefore $n$ could be $2$,
  but my teacher told me that there is a number which is bigger than $2$.

I've tried to solve it many times, but unfortunately I didn't get any solution. So I hope that you can help me to approach this problem.

Comment: Did you really need to enclose all your text in dollar signs?

Comment: Why man, why. I can't even edit it without considerable effort due to all the backslashes..

Comment: Life is hard...

Comment: Why don't you try to similar things that worked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/596074/11619)?

Comment: For example by Little Fermat we know that $19\mid n^{19}-n$ for all $n$. Do you see how that implies that $19\mid n^{55}-n$ for all $n$ also? Same with $3$ and $7$?

Comment: To aid the search:
$$2^{55}-2=2\cdot3^4\cdot7\cdot19\cdot73\cdot87211\cdot262657.$$ Check the highest power of $3$ dividing $3^{55}-3$ and use what you know about primitive roots to deal with the larger primes.

Comment: @Jyrki But there is no need to factor any large numbers. It suffices to factor $54$ - see my answer.

Comment: @Bill Agreed. That was admittedly a Sonnhardish way of going about it. Mind you, I was mildly worried about divisibility by prime powers. Your other answer saves the day :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Oh no, it's contagious?  That way can be useful when less is known, e.g. if we have instead of $\,n^5-n\,$ some arbitrary sequence $\,f(n)\,$ then we can take the gcd of the first few values to attempt to gain some insight.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By the Theorem below we deduce $\,k\mid n^{\large 55}-n\,$ for all $n$ iff $\,k\,$ is a product of distinct primes $p$ such that $\,p-1\mid 54$, i.e. $\,p =2,3,7,19.\,$ Thus the largest such $k$ is their product $= 798.$

**Theorem** $\ $  For natural numbers $\rm\:a,e,n\:$ with $\rm\:e,n>1$

$\qquad\rm n\:|\:a^{\large e}-a\:$ for all $\rm\:a\:\iff  n\:$ is squarefree, and prime $\rm\:p\:|\:n\:\Rightarrow\: p\!-\!1\:|\:e\!-\!1$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\ \ $ Since a squarefree natural divides another iff all its 
prime factors do, we need only show $\rm\:p\:|\:a^{\large e}\!-\!a\:$ for each prime $\rm\:p\:|\:n,\:$ or, 
that $\rm\:a \not\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\: a^{\large e-1} \equiv 1\pmod p,\:$ which, since $\rm\:p\!-\!1\:|\:e\!-\!1,\:$ follows 
from $\rm\:a \not\equiv 0\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\: a^{\large p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p,\:$ by little Fermat.
$(\Rightarrow)\ \ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164568/242).