# How to prove that $n^5 - n$ is a multiple of $5$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Hello I'm new to induction so please bare with me. For this problem I have to use induction to prove: For every integer $n\geq 1$, the number $n^5 − n$ is a multiple of $5$. Can someone please help me figure this out. I've tried to follow the examples in the book, but they were very confusing.

Comment: Already answered:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350675/prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-5-by-induction.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Ok thanks! Sorry for posting a duplicate question.

Comment: A way to prove this without induction is to look at the factorization $n^5-n=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2-4+5)=(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)+5n(n^2-1)$. A product of 5 consecutive integers is divisible by $5$, which can be shown using division with remainder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly for $n = 1$: $1^5 - 1 = $ which is a multiple of $5$

Induction Hypothesis $5$ divides $n^5 - n$. We need to show: $5$ divides $(n+1)^5 - (n+1)$.

Now, $(n+1)^5 - (n+1)$ = $n^5 + 5n^4 + 10n^3 + 10n^2 + 5n +1-n -1$. So $5$ divides $(n+1)^5 - (n+1)$.

So by Principle of Mathematical Induction $5$ divides $n^5 - n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\Large\tt A "Non-Induction" Proof$:

> Let $n = p + \delta$ where $p\in{\mathbb N}$. $10|p$.
>   $0 \leq \delta \leq 9$. Then,
>   $$
> n^{5} = \pars{p + \delta}^{5}
> = \overbrace{%
> p^{5} + 5p^{4}\delta + 10p^{3}\delta^{2} + 10p^{2}\delta^{3} + 5p\delta^{4}}
> ^{\mbox{Obviosusly, it's a multiple of}\ 10}\ +\ \delta^{5}
> $$
>   $\delta^{5} \in \braces{\color{#00f}{\large 0},\color{#00f}{\large 1},3\color{#00f}{\large 2},24\color{#00f}{\large 3},102\color{#00f}{\large 4},312\color{#00f}{\large 5},777\color{#00f}{\large 6},1680\color{#00f}{\large 7},3276\color{#00f}{\large 8},5904\color{#00f}{\large 9}}$ such that the last digit of $n^{5}$ is equal to $\delta$. Then, the last digits of $n$ and $n^{5}$ are equal which means that the last digit of $n^{5} - n$ is zero and
>   $\color{#00f}{\large 5 | \pars{n^{5} - n}}$.

Comment: Beautiful! :-) (+1)

Answer (score 3):

**Base** case, $n=1$:  $1^5-1=0$ is divisible by 5.

**Hypothesis**: $\exists n \geq 1: 5|(n^5-n)$

**Step**:
$$(n+1)^5-(n+1)= (\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{5}{k}n^k) - (n+1) \\ = 1+ 5n+ 10n^2 + 10n^3+5n^4+n^5-n-1=5(n+2n+2n^2+n^4) + n^5-n$$
Now by the hypothesis $5|(n^5-n)$, and clearly $5|[5(n+2n+2n^2+n^4)]$, and therefore:
$$ 5|[(n+1)^5-(n+1)]$$

This completes the proof by induction and it follows that:
$$\forall n \geq 1: 5|(n^5-n)$$

If you **don't believe in induction** (I don't believe in induction, because it has nothing to do with belief ;-):
$$n^5-n = n(n^4-1) = n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=(n-1)n(n+1)(n^2+1)$$
Now, if:
$$(n-1 \equiv 0 \bmod 5) \oplus (n \equiv 0 \bmod 5) \oplus (n+1 \equiv 0 \bmod 5)$$ 
We are done. If not, then:
$$(n-2 \equiv 0 \bmod 5) \oplus (n+2 \equiv 0 \bmod 5)$$
Must hold. Now notice that $(n-2)(n+2)=n^2-4 \equiv n^2+1\bmod 5$.

So in this case, using modular multiplication rules, $n^2+1 \equiv 0 \bmod 5$ must hold.

So there's no escape! $5|(n^5-n)$.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to show another approach without induction method

We know that

$$n^5 - n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=(n-1)n(n+1)(n^2+1)$$

Now Let's focus on another sequence

$ n>2$ and $k>0$

$$(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)= 5.k$$

Because if we have 5 numbers sequence and always we will have a number in the sequence such form of $5.j$.

Examples:

$3.4.5.6.7$

or 
$4.5.6.7.8$

or
$5.6.7.8.9$

or 
$6.7.8.9.10$

another sequence also must be such form of

$$(n-1)n(n+1).5= 5.m$$

$$(n-1)n(n+1)(n^2-4)= 5.k$$

To sum up both terms , you can get

$$(n-1)n(n+1)(n^2-4+5)= 5(m+k)$$

$$(n-1)n(n+1)(n^2+1)=n^5 - n= 5.(k+m)$$

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

Base case $n = 1: 1^5 - 1 = 0 = 0*5$ which is a multiple of $5 ( k = 0 )$.

Assume $5$ divides $n^5 - n$. We need to show: $5$ divides $(n+1)^5 - (n+1)$.

$(n+1)^5 - (n+1) = n^5 + 5k + 1 - (n+1) = 5k + n^5 - n$. We have: $5$ divides $5k$, and from induction step: $5$ divides $n^5 - n$. So $5$ divides $(n+1)^5 - (n+1)$.

So: $5$ divides $n^5 - n$ for all $n$.